# Create React App index.html issues with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, gatsby

I have a Create-React-App project that I want to convert to Gatsby. It has everything, src folder, index.js, etc. but also a public folder. However, this public folder is then used by Gatsby to do whatever they do.

Unfortunately, when they put the files into the public folder, it erases mine.

My question is quite simple: where can I put my index.html file so it won't be erased by Gatsby. I can't get rid of it since React won't know where to put the code and I wouldn't be able to charge my Favicons.

I am feeling lost trying to learn Gatsby and everything and this is one of the last obstacle preventing me from creating my first Gatsby app.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

Comment: @DaveNewton And where do I call html.js? I am still confused.

Comment: Call it? Just follow the directions. Or maybe https://flaviocopes.com/gatsby-change-favicon/. Or use Helmet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical structure in any Gatsby project looks like:

```
/
|-- /.cache
|-- /plugins
|-- /public
|-- /src
    |-- /pages
    |-- /templates
    |-- html.js
|-- /static
|-- gatsby-config.js
|-- gatsby-node.js
|-- gatsby-ssr.js
|-- gatsby-browser.js
```

Everything inside `/src`, is compiled into `/public`. The public folder is overwritten in each build/compilation so your code must not be there, that's why is erased in your scenario. Your logic must remain under `/src`. So summarizing, you must deploy your `/public` folder and develop in `/src`.

Answering your question, your `index.html` will be under `/src/index.js`. Since Gatsby, by default, takes the `/pages` structure and replicates it into pages in `/public`. So, everything under the first level of `/pages` will be converted as `domain.com/page-name`. If you place a folder inside `/src`, like `/blog` (second level), everything inside it will be converted as `domain.com/blog/page-name` and so on with nested folders.

Regarding the favicon, Gatsby is a plugin-based framework, you can do it manually or using one of the useful plugins, such as [`gatsby-plugin-manifest`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-manifest/).

I would recommend you to start reading [this documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-project-structure/) to understand how Gatsby works.

Comment: If I remember correct, the static folder content is copied to public without any processing. If you do not "produce" an index.html with index.js in the source folder, you could place your own index.html in the static folder. The Gatsby way would be to convert your index.html to index.js as described above.

Comment: You're right @Stefan , everything inside `/static` it's transpiled with the same internal structure in `/public`. However, the question is about moving a React app to Gatsby, therefore, I assume that he don't want to use a native HTML structure to create an `index.html`. I inferred by the question that he doesn't know the internal structure of Gatsby and why everything inside `/public` is lost in each compilation.